# How to add an image to a link to share it on Facebook

Tags: image, facebook, post, share

I am implementing a button to share posts on Facebook and my problem is that when I share the link of a post through "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + POST_URL + "&amp" it is shared with the thumbnail, description, correctly but I have some other links that are pdf files that I need to be shared in the same way but are only being shared with the link, without preview and image. I want to know if it is possible to concatenate an image to a link to share it on Facebook.

I tried to concatenate the image to the link like this: &picture=URL_IMAGE but it does not work.

**Example links**

Sharing a pdf file: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.africau.edu%2Fimages%2Fdefault%2Fsample.pdf&amp%3Bsrc=sdkpreparse

Sharing a new: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2Fes%2F2020%2F05%2F26%2Fespanol%2Fcoronavirus-superficies-como-se-transmite.html&amp%3Bsrc=sdkpreparse

Thanks

Comment: No, that is not possible by manipulating anything about the URL. You can link to an HTML document that serves the necessary OG meta data to Facebook, and redirects human visitors to the PDF file via JavaScript. Or do it server-side, by checking the User-Agent header of the request; if that is from the Facebook scraper, you serve the HTML document, otherwise the PDF.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help!. That was the solution, put the pdf inside an iframe inside an HTML document and it turned out fine. Thanks